# git status muestra cambios pero no aparece simbolo de M en los files

Tags: git, github

Cuando en el terminal hago git status me muestra que hay modificaciones, pero la lista de files de la izquierda, antes cuando hacia un cambio me ponia una M al lado, o una U si era nuevo, pero ahora no muestra eso, solo aparecen los cambios si hago el git status en el terminal

Comment: un `^M` al mirar con `git diff`? Eso lo usa git para indicar un salto de línea tipo Güindous. Si el archivo es tipo UNIX, entonces no coloca eso al final de una línea agregada.

Comment: Prueba con `git status -s`